# Update query using data from three tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three table,`familycall` table is this:
[image]

and `CDR` table is this:

[image]

and `FamilyCallDetail` is this:

[image]

I want write this update query:

```
update FamilyCallDetail
where familyCallDetail.Anumber=under select query anumber
set duration=duration+(
    select anumber,sum(duration)
    where familyCall.anumber=Cdr.Anumber and FamilyCall.Bnumber=Cdr.Bnumber

)
```

How can i write that update query?thanks for every one.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to do. Your `UPDATE` statement is trying to apply a 2 column result set to a scalar value. Please can you give expected results in your question.

Comment: please post code as text

Comment: @ChrisPickford I'm beginner in stack over flow usage.

Comment: @ChrisPickford my friend,that update query is my syntax,i want convert that synax to real query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
;
WITH CTE_Aggregate AS (
  SELECT
    fc.Anumber,
    SUM(cdr.Duration) AS Duration
  FROM FamilyCall AS fc
  INNER JOIN CDR AS cdr
    ON cdr.Anumber = fc.Anumber
    AND cdr.Bnumber = fc.Bnumber
  GROUP BY fc.Anumber
)
UPDATE fcd
SET fcd.Duration = fcd.Duration + cte.Duration
FROM FamilyCallDetail fcd
INNER JOIN CTE_Aggregate AS cte
  ON cte.Anumber = fcd.Anumber;
```

Comment: thanks my friend for help me,your query is work for my purpose,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what you actually want to do. Probably this?

```
update FamilyCallDetail
where familyCallDetail.Anumber = IN (select query anumber)
set duration = duration + (
    select sum(duration)
    FROM Cdr 
        innner join FamilyCall on (
          Crd.Anumber = FamilyCall.Anumber 
          and Cdr.Bnumber = FamiliyCall.Bnumber)
    where familyCall.anumber=FamilyCallDetail.Anumber
)
```

It adds the duration of all Cdr's to the FamiliyCallDetail, which have the same Anumber and which have an entry in FamilyCall linked by Anumber and Bnumber. I'm not sure if the Bnumber and the FamilyCall is actually relevant. If not, it gets much simpler.